# Where was Jesus before he went to Galilee in John 1:43?

Tags: john, new-testament, gospels, john-the-baptist, geography

Where was Jesus before he went to Galilee in John 1:43?

> The next day Jesus decided to go to Galilee.
> (John 1:43a, ESV)

In 1:35, Jesus was near John the Baptist. In 1:37, the two disciples follow Jesus to where he is staying.  In 2:42, Jesus spoke to Peter.

Jesus went to Galilee.

Jesus called Philip. Philip was from Bethsaida (a town on the northern shores of Galilee), the city that Andrew and Peter were from (John 1:44).

Another way to ask the same question is, "Where did Jesus talk to Peter before 1:43?"  Watching a Gospel of John film is what brought this up.  The movie had Andrew meeting Peter when he landed a boat from a lake.  The lake in that area with fish was the Sea of Galilee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is supplied by John 1:28 -

> 28 All this happened at Bethany beyond the Jordan, where John was
> baptizing.

The problem is now, "Where is the Bethany of V28?"  This is a much debated point since the time of the early church fathers.  The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary offers this summary of the debate:

> 28. Bethabara—Rather, "Bethany" (according to nearly all the best and most ancient manuscripts); not the Bethany of Lazarus, but another of
>     the same name, and distinguished from it as lying "beyond Jordan," on
>     the east.

Thus, the location now appears to have been lost but distinct from Galilee and further south.

Comment: So the movie must have taken Bethany (Beyond the Jordan) as not too far from the mouth of the Jordan river at the south end of the Sea of Galilee.  The movie apparently had Andrew meeting Peter disembarking from his boat at the south end of the Sea of Galilee.

Comment: @PerryWebb - the current "betting" is that Bethany was possibly closer to Jerusalem than Galilee.  But that is a guess!